# Ipython get stuck in bash

Tags: bash, ipython

[image]

As showed in the above picture, I am trying to use the run `Ipython` with the bash terminal, but it just stuck, without any interactive interface comes out. 
I am trying to stop it by `Ctrl+z`, it also can't work, I have to open another terminal and kill it by the process ID.

But when I run the original `python` command, it can work normally.

I installed the `Ipython` with pip, the install command is just the normal one.

`pip install ipython`

But I don't why it can not work? I installed `Ipython` a lots of times on other linux servers, I never encountered this kind of problems before.

Do I missed some dependency packages for Ipython?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anaconda ? You can use anaconda to open ipython

Comment: Hi, I didn't use anaconda, I just installled `Ipython` with `pip`.